# JOIN in SQL query for matched results from two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem in a SQL query.

There are two tables:

1: `POrder` with columns:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PO_Date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[PO_No] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Party_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Currency] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Total_Value] [numeric](12, 2) NULL,
[Remarks] [varchar](250) NULL,
[PO_Status] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Y_CODE] [varchar](4) NULL,
```

2: `Invoice` with columns:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Y_Code] [varchar](4) NULL,
[Inv_Date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[Inv_No] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[PO_No] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Party_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Total_Value] [numeric](12, 2) NULL,
[Remarks] [varchar](250) NULL,
[Inv_Status] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Complete_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[OPI_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[Pmt_Status] [varchar](10) NULL,
```

For a row in `POrder` there may be multiple rows in the `Invoice` table.

I have to determine whether - given a row in `POrder` - there are any rows in `Invoice`. `PO_No` is common column in both tables.

Result should be like:

```
PO_No   Billed
11      Yes (if row(s) found in invoice) 
12      No  (if no row found in invoice)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
SELECT po.PO_No,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Invoice
     WHERE PO_No = po.PO_No) AS Billed
FROM POrder po
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 (LEFT OUTER JOIN with DISTINCT):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
p.PO_No,
(CASE WHEN i.PO_No IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END) AS Billed
FROM POrder p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice i ON i.PO_No = p.PO_No
ORDER BY p.PO_No ASC
```

Option 2 (SUBSELECT):

```
SELECT
PO_No,
(CASE WHEN C > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Billed
FROM
(
SELECT 
p.PO_No,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Invoice i WHERE i.PO_No = p.PO_No) AS C
FROM POrder p
)
ORDER BY PO_No ASC
```